# multiple javascript events fired by pusher js library

Tags: pusher

i am implementing pusher with php library for notification system. Everything was running fine until i discovered that including pusher js library fires all the javascript/jQuery events twice. There is a case where admin edits the applicat's details and saves it via ajax request. If i don't include pusher js library it send only one ajax request for saving but if i include pusher library then ajax request are sent twice. i was also having trouble with jQuery toggle() where event is fired twice so instead of showing the content of the div that i applied toggle() event it shows and hide the content of the div in quick succession.

Comment: So, what are you asking?

Comment: I think the question is "Why does including the pusher-js library result in additional ajax calls being made within the application?" I think we're going to need some sample code that replicates the problem in order to help.

Comment: Are you talkning about jquery pusher? (https://github.com/salvan13/jquery-pusher)